# Grub сломан arch linux

Tags: linux, unix, grub, archlinux

У меня установлен arch linux, каждый раз когда я подключаю bootable флешку и выключаю компьютер grub слетает и запускается с grub-shell. Приходится каждый раз переконфигурировать граб. Конфиг сгенерирован автоматически утилитой grub-mkconfig. Устоновлен os prober. Я подозреваю что проблема скорее всего в grub.cfg, но в чем конкретно она может быть?

Comment: Может логи выключения посмотреть?

Comment: *подключаю bootable флешку и выключаю компьютер* - что значит *выключаю* ? Кнопкой питания? Перед тем, как *выключить* компьютер, Вы флэшку размонтируете? Такое впечатление, что при последующей загрузки grub пытается загружаться с флэшки.